# Produce HTML output from AWS EMR Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, pandas-profiling

I'm currently running a default/basic notebook on EMR (Release label: emr-6.1.0, Applications: Spark 3.0.0, Zeppelin 0.9.0, JupyterHub 1.1.0) and i'm having some issues getting the notebook to output a data profiling report in HTML.

I've installed [pandas-profiling](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling) a variety of ways, using custom bootstrap actions & with the command `sc.install_pypi_package("pandas-profiling")`

I run into the following issue after trying to generate the report's HTML using IPython. It only produces the object vs the HTML.

[image]

I'm also aware that adding `%%local` can help produce it, like below.

[image]

But installing through bootstrap actions/on the notebook does not install from wherever `%%local` is located. As seen below.

[image]

So my first question is, can this profile report be produced without the `%%local` magic? I know there is also an `%%html` magic command, but that cannot print out a variable based on my testing, hence why I need IPython.

Second question is, how can `pandas-profiling` be added to this `%%local` environment? Should this even be the approach?

Thanks!!